# Count number of mutual friends in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to pull the number of mutual friends that I have with any given userID. I first pulled all my friends from Firebase and then I pulled the userID's friends. I'm just not sure how to count the number of mutual friends from there. Please let me know if I'm going about it the wrong way.

```
func fetchMutualFriends(myID: String, userID: String) {

    let myID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

    let postRef = self.databaseRef.child("friends").child(myID)

    postRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for childSnapshot in snapshot.children {
              print(childSnapshot)

        }
    })
    let postRef1 = self.databaseRef.child("friends").child(friendID)

    postRef1.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for childSnapshot in snapshot.children {
            print(childSnapshot)

        }
    })
}
```

Firebase structure

```
root/
|___ friends/
|      |___ myID
|              |___ friendID1
|      |___ friendID1
|              |___ myID
```

Comment: Check this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#/c:objc(cs)FIRDataSnapshot(im)hasChild:), i don't know swift but as i look in to your code you can use `hasChild`.put your `postRef1.observe` inside the first one and check any your friends present in other user friend list and update a counter.

Comment: Can you please post some sample data for `childSnapshot` to know the structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering Firebase Database for Mutual Friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46270843/filtering-firebase-database-for-mutual-friends)

Comment: @JoshCaswell While I agree it may be a duplicate, there is no answer to the other question so marking as dup doesn't really help. More importantly, neither question includes the OP's Firebase structure and based on that structure the answers could be completely different.

Comment: Yes, you are going about this the wrong way. Include your Firebase structure as TEXT please, NO images and that would help us form an accurate answer.

Comment: This is a _repost_, @Jay, not a duplicate. In fact this user has about 6 questions that all seem to be different phrasings of the same problem.  "Duplicate" is just the only means we have to mark such a thing.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Well, Ill be. Yes. You are totally correct! Look at that, and here's [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46534571/fetch-user-info-and-append-to-an-array) similar question. Good catch. To the OP - it would be best to try to roll these questions together into one instead of asking the same question several different ways.

Comment: While you have a kinda-structure in your question, it's not the actual structure. i.e. it looks like myID has a child node friendID1 or is friendID1 the value of myID? See? That's why we need to look at your *actual* structure so understand what keys and what values you are using and how they relate? (set to true? 0 and 1 or something else?) Firebase Console->Export JSON and include a short snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the actual struture is not clear, let's assume a standard structure like this

```
  "users"
    "user_0"
      "friends"
        "user_1" : true,
        "user_2" : true,
        "user_3" : true
    "user_1" 
      "friends"
        "user_0" : true,
        "user_2" : true
    "user_2"
      "friends"
        "user_0" : true,
        "user_1" : true,
        "user_3" : true
    "user_3"
      "friends"
        "user_0" : true,
        "user_2" : true
```

As you can see, user 0 is friends with user_1, user_2 and user_3, and likewise in their nodes those users are friends with user_0.

If we want to keep this structure then finding the intersection of two users mutual friends is pretty easy.

Suppose we want to find which friends user_0 and user_2 have in common. Looking at the structure we find it's

```
user_1
user_3
```

How do we do that in code?

```
let user1FriendsRef = self.ref.child("users").child("user_0").child("friends")
let user2FriendsRef = self.ref.child("users").child("user_2").child("friends")

user1FriendsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { user1Snapshot in
    let user1FriendsArray = user1Snapshot.children.map { ($0 as! DataSnapshot).key }
    let user1FriendsSet = Set(user1FriendsArray)

    user2FriendsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { user2Snapshot in
        let user2FriendsArray = user2Snapshot.children.map { ($0 as! DataSnapshot).key }
        let user2FriendsSet = Set(user2FriendsArray)

        let mutualFriends = user1FriendsSet.intersection(user2FriendsSet).sorted()
        print(mutualFriends)
        print(mutualFriends.count)
    })
})
```

Here's how that code works: We start with a reference to the two users friends lists we want to compare

Using observeSingleEvent, the first users friends list is read and the keys  (user_1, user_2 etc) are stored in an array. That is done my mapping (iterating over) each key: value pair to capture the key. That array is converted to a Set var.

We do the same thing for the second user - noting it's important we do that within the first closure so we are guaranteed the results from the first user are complete. Those results are mapped to an array and the made into a Set.

Then, the magic of leveraging the intersection function of a Set and then print the mutual friends (sorted)

```
["user_1", "user_3"]
2
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to extend this to include not just mutual friends, but also friend of friends? so if I'm only friends with user_2, and user_2 is friends with me and user_3, I would like an array that includes user_2 and user_3?

Comment: @johnsmith Absolutely! One approach would be to query for all users that are your friends and then iterate through each of their friends lists. However, that's a different (and really good!) question and should be posted separately. In this answer we focused on getting and counting the number of mutual friends. This solution is compact, and concise and very maintainable. If this answer answered this question, please be sure to accept it. Post your followup (and more complex) question and we'll take a look. We *really* need to see your structure for that one though as it's more complex.

Comment: Great, I have accepted your answer! The other question is essentially this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47645729/querying-friend-of-friends-with-swift

Answer (score 1):

It would help a lot if you post the structure of your database in your question.

I assume it looks something like this:

```
root/
|___ users/
|      |___ userID1
|              |___ name : user_name
|              |___ email : user_email
|              |___ picUrl : user_picture_url
|              |___ friends
|                       |___ userID2 : true                    
|                       |___ userID3 : true
|                        ...
```

I added a lot of comments in the code below to make it easier for you to see every step.

So, this is how you could write your `fetchMutualFriends` method:

```
    func fetchMutualFriends(userID: String) {

         // Use a guard statement here to make sure your current user object is not nil

        guard let currentUserID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
             return
        }

        // Create two arrays to store the two friend lists:

        var friendListA = [String]()
        var friendListB = [String]()

        // Create a dispatch group:

        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

        // Enter the dispatch group

        dispatchGroup.enter()

        // Add the observers:

        // Depending on your database structure, you may want to adjust the references below:

        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUserID).child("friends").child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self] (snapshot : DataSnapshot) in

                      // Iterate through all the children:    

                      for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                          // Add the user ID to the array:
                           self?.friendListA.append(child.key)
                      })

                      if snapshot.childrenCount == 0 {
                           // TODO: Handle the case when there is no friend in the friend list.
                      }

                     // Leave the dispatch group    

                     dispatchGroup.leave()
        })


        dispatchGroup.enter()


        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userID).child("friends").child(currentUserID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot : DataSnapshot) in

                     // Iterate through all the children:    

                      for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                          // Add the user ID to the array:
                           self?.friendListB.append(child.key)
                      })

                      if snapshot.childrenCount == 0 {
                           // TODO: Handle the case when there is no friend in the friend list.
                      }

                     // Leave the dispatch group    

                     dispatchGroup.leave()
       })

      // Notify the dispatch group:

      dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {

               // Now that both completion blocks (from your two observers) ran, you can compare the two friend lists and see if they have any friends in common:

               let commonFriendsArray  = friendListA.filter { friendListB.contains($0) }

               // Do whatever you want with the common friends list :)

        })


   }
```

Comment: Thank you - I'm getting an error saying "Value of type 'TableViewController' has no member 'friendListA'. Any advice there?

Comment: You're welcome @johnsmith! Sure, if you want to use friendListA in your table view controller, you need to declare it outside from the fetchMutualFriends method. I declared friendListA and friendListB inside the function just to show you an example:)

Comment: @johnsmith While this is an accepted answer, it's WAY overly complex for you're doing. If you can update your question with a snippet of your actual Firebase structure there are far simpler ways to get a count.

Comment: In addition to the count, can you also help me with a way to pull all the mutual friend IDs in an array?

Comment: @johnsmith Happy to help. See my answer that does both: gets the count and stores them in an array (Set) with a minimal amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **numChildren()** function which returns the number of child properties of a DataSnapshot.
Assume we have the following data in the Database:

```
{
  "name": {
    "first": "Ada",
    "last": "Lovelace"
  }
}
```

If I want to know the number of childs of name for example :

```
var b = snapshot.child("name").numChildren(); // 2 ("first", "last")
```

If I want to know the number of childs of first for example :

```
var c = snapshot.child("name/first").numChildren(); // 0
```

Hope it will guide you.