# Querying friend of friends with Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to pull a list of my friends and my friend's friends using Firebase. Right now, I'm pulling my list of friends and then looping through their friends to pull their user ID. I would like to append it to a single array with the output ["friendID1","friendID2", "friendID3", "friendID4","friendID5"]. My code so far:

```
 Database.database().reference().child("friends").child(myID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot : DataSnapshot) in

       for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

            let value = child.value as? NSDictionary

            let userId = value?["userId"] as? String ?? ""

         Database.database().reference().child("friends").child(friendID1).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot : DataSnapshot) in


                for child1 in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {


                    let value1 = child1.value as? NSDictionary

                    let userId1 = value1?["userId"] as? String ?? ""
                    self.friendArray.append(userId1)                   
                }
            })
        }
  })
```

Firebase structure

```
{
    "friends" : {
        “currentUserId” : {
            “friendId1” : {
                “Confirmed” : "yes"
            },
            “friendId3” : {
                “Confirmed” : “Yes”,
            }
            “friendId5” : {
                “Confirmed” : “Yes”,
            }
        },
        “friendId1” : {
            “CurrentUserId” : {
                “Confirmed” : "yes"
            },
            “friendId2” : {
                “Confirmed” : “Yes”,
            }
        },
        “friendId3” : {
            “CurrentUserId” : {
                “Confirmed” : "yes"
            },
            “friendId4” : {
                “Confirmed” : “Yes”,
            }
        },
}
```

Comment: For reference, there was an initial question [Count Mutual Friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46383673/count-number-of-mutual-friends-in-firebase/47640285?noredirect=1#comment82250012_47640285) that lead to this more complex question. It's similar but not a duplicate.

Comment: Can you please post your *actual* firebase structure? What you have is conceptual and doesn't describe the actual key: value pairs of how the data is stored in Firebase. As it is, it appears you can just observe the friendID1 node and map the child keys from the resultant snapshot to an array, omitting myID. So the keys friendID2, friendID3 and friendID4 would be put into an array. The code would be similar to the code in my answer to your initial question. If that's not correct, then clarifying this question a tad would help.

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more clear and not exactly sure what you mean by actual firebase structure, but I've edited my question and firebase a bit. Essentially, I would like a way to look through my current friends and pull their friends and combine it all into a single array.

Comment: The actual Firebase structure is exactly what it looks like in Firebase, you can get that from the Firebase Console->Export JSON. The structure in your question is conceptual - we don't know what the keys and values are of each node. is friendID1 a *key* or a *value*? If it's a key, what is it's value - if it's a value what is it's key.

Comment: No problem - Firebase added above!

Comment: @Jay any ideas Jay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure you're using is going to cause issues. I would change it to this simple structure:

```
users
  user_0
    friends
      user_1: true
  user_1
    friends
      user_0: true
      user_2: true
  user_2
    friends
      user_1: true
      user_3: true
  user_3
    friends
      user_2: true
```

Then do a query on all of the user nodes that contain my user id.

Assume I am user_0 and want to know my friends, friends

So in this case, my friend is user_1, and user_1's friends are user_0 (me) and user_2. The result should be user_2

Here's the code.

```
let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")
let queryRef = usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "friends/user_0")
                       .queryEqual(toValue: true)
queryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

    var friendsSet = Set<String>()
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let friendsSnap = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "friends")

        for friendChild in friendsSnap.children {
            let friendSnap = friendChild as! DataSnapshot
            let uid = friendSnap.key
            friendsSet.insert(uid)
        }
    }

    if let index = friendsSet.index(of: "user_0") {
        friendsSet.remove(at: index)
    }

    for uid in friendsSet {
        print(uid)
    } 
})
```

and the result is

```
user_2
```

likewise, if I am user_2 and want to know my friends, friends I would want to know user_1's friends and user_3'friends

and the result is

```
user_0
```

This is a simple example, but if user_0 had friends user_1 and user_2 and they had multiple friends, the output would be all of their friends.

Oh - in case you want them sorted...

```
let sortedFrieds = friendsSet.sorted()
```

Discussion:

The real magic that makes this work is a Firebase Deep Query - that allows us to drill down one level below the child nodes we are querying. In this case we are querying for all user_x/friends/user_0 equals true.

That snapshot will contain all users that have my (user_0) as a child node. I can then iterate over those users friends nodes and add each key, which is the user id, to a Set.

The Set it being used instead of an Array as we only want unique values stored and for the moment don't care about ordering.

We then toss out my user id (user_0) and the print the result.

Comment: you've been extremely helpful with my questions. Do you mind helping me think through this request? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47763444/retrieving-common-values-in-firebase