# Retrieving common values in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What's the most efficient way to pull all common elements from Firebase? I'm trying to pull all posts where the postName is the same and get their respective userId and append it into an array. Based on the database structure below, the output should be ["userId1","userId2","userId4", "userId5"].

```
func fetchPosts() {

    let usersRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")

    usersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

            let value = child.value as? NSDictionary

            let postName = value?["postName"] as? String ?? ""

            //check for postName that have the same value
            //for each of those postName, fetch their relevant userId
        }
    })
}
```

Database structure

```
_Posts
__postId1
____postName: "Common"
____userId: "userId1"
__postId2
____postName: "Common"
____userId: "userId2"
__postId3
____postName: "Not common"
____userId: "userId3"
__postId4
____postName: "Also common"
____userId: "userId4"
__postId5
____postName: "Also common"
____userId: "userId5"
```

Comment: This would be done through a query like let queryRef = postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "postName").queryEqual(toValue: "Common"). Is that what you are asking how to do? [Working With Lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data) in the Sorting and Filtering section.

Comment: Yes, except that it's not always the word "Common". I want to search through the database to find all words that are the same - I edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: You're not going to be able to directly do that. What you are asking is to query for all nodes where postName is not unique. There may be alternative structures what would help accomplish this task. Can you provide a real-world use case for why you want to do that?

Comment: Sure, the real life example is seen within Facebook. If two people say they like "Stack Overflow", they can produce an output that says "2 of your friends like Stack overflow". If there is an easier way to do this, happy to know.

Comment: Ah - that's different because it's not finding common values or duplicates, it's counting how many times the word 'Stack Overflow" appears. It will also say "1 of your friends likes Stack Overflow'. There's a bigger picture here though; when you like something, a reference to what you liked is added to your 'likes' node and then back end code will query all of your friends to see if they like the same thing, counting them as it goes. So if you like Stack Overflow (reference # xyzzy) as soon as you do that, all of your friends likes nodes are queried for xyzzy and counted.